# An operator issue in JS

Tags: javascript, operators

code block 1:

```
var a = (1 + - + + + - + 1); 
alert(a); //2
```

Why does a equal 2?

code block 2:

```
var a = (1+-+++-+1);
alert(a); //ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

When using spaces in your expression it is discarding the previous operator this is why code block two errors and code block one is basically doing:

`var a = (1 + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is just [basic math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). It gets grouped and evaluates like this

```
1 + (- (+ (+ (+ (- (+ 1))))))
```

It isn't discarding the previous operators. It's just using the basic law that `-` multiplied by `+` is `-`.
 For example, the following is just being grouped like `1 - (+ 1)` which is `1 - 1` which is `0`

```
1 - + 1 // 0
```

Now, when you don't use space, the javascript interprets it as increment and decrement operators and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

First, the other answer are correct as to the "weird" behavior in the first case. The reason you're getting the `ReferenceError` in the second case without the spaces is because two of those `+`s are being treated as the `++` increment command.

`1+-+(+(+-1))` won't give you an error